# HtmlUnit does not redirect properly after upgrading jQuery from 1.7 to 1.8.1

Tags: java, ajax, testing, selenium, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit 2.10 to click a link which triggers a JavaScript that redirects to another URL. JavaScript uses window.location to redirect. The result is not the same as if I open the page directly with the URL. The redirection page result looks as if the page is still loading, although it's not.

When looking at the requests sent it looks as if HtmlUnit requests the page and even send the ajax-requests FROM the page I'm trying to get redirected to, but does not show it. I've tried IO-writing "page.asXml()" into a .html file to get a preview of the page, and it contains almost nothing, as if it's still loading the new content. But, I've also tried waiting for up to 100 seconds for the page to load with

```
synchronized (page) {
   page.wait(int x);
}
```

and it does not make any difference to the result.

I cannot give a reproducable script for this error since the page is run locally only at the moment.

Any thoughts as to what can be wrong?

**Edit: I can add that this problem seemed to arrive with the upgrade to jQuery 1.8.1 from jQuery 1.7.0.**

Answer (score 0):

Still i do not see clearly the way how to resolve completely your problem, but I've got an assumption how to investigate your problem deeper(i.e. wheter you've been redirected properly or not):
localize 1 -2 elements on the page you want be redirected with cssSelector or xpath.
then after redirecting call fluentWait()

```
  public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
            Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

            WebElement foo = wait.until(
    new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                            return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                    }
    );
                               return  foo;              }     ;
```

you can read about fluent wait [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

If it returns web element on the page u've been redirected to. Otherwise it fails.
Hope this somehow helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using HtmlUnit so it's WebClient not WebDriver. Besides, I've tried waiting for upwards of 100 seconds then finding the element. The page simply does not load, which is really peculiar since the requests are sent and response is recieved with the correct content... just not shown in HtmlUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the WebClient to have it's `redirectEnabled` field set to `true`. To do this, simply add this line before you execute the request...

```
webClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);
```

This will ensure redirects are followed by the HtmlUnit client.

[Here are the docs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setRedirectEnabled%28boolean%29) for the method.

Comment: Thanks, but setDirectEnabled is set to true. Besides, these only work for server redirect status codes, and this is JavaScript redirecting.

Comment: Ya, I read the question a second time and realized you were redirecting with JavaScript and I suspected this property wouldn't make a difference. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I'm going to try to use the latest build from SVN, instead of the stable 2.10 build.